# I need help for building a regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

It is my first time working with regex and I am a little lost. To give you a little background, I am making a program that reads a text file line by line and it saves in a string called "line". If the line starts with either a tab o or a whitespace, followed by a number or number and dots (such as 1 or 1.2.1, for instance) followed by another tab or whitespace, it copies the line to another file.

So far I build this regex, but it does not work

```
            string pattern = @"(\t| ) *[0-9.] (\t| )";

            if (line.StartsWith(pattern))
            {

                //copy line

            }
```

Also, is line.StartsWith correct? Or should I use something like rgx.Matches(pattern)?

Comment: `string.StartsWith()` does not recognize regular expressions. You need `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern contains a character class without a quantifier, which will match either a single digit or dot.

To prevent matching for example only dots you could first match digits followed by an optional part which matches a dot and then again digits `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*`

Note that in this part `(\t| )`  there are 2 characters expected to match as the space in that part has meaning.

You could simplify the pattern to use a character class to match either a tab or space instead of using an alternation and if you don't need the capturing group you could omit it.

Instead of using [StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8) you could usefor example [IsMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.8)

```
^[ \t][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*[ \t]
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[ \t]` Match a single tab or space
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits 0-9
- `(?:\.[0-9]+)*` Repeat 0+ times a dot and 1+ digits
- `[ \t]` Match a single tab or space

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b+%5ct%5d%5b0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b0-9%5d%2b%29*%5b+%5ct%5d&i=+1+%0d%0a%091.2.1+%0d%0a%09....+&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/taNlLr)

For example

```
string s = "\t1.2.1 ";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[ \t][0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*[ \t]");

if (regex.IsMatch(s)) {
    //copy line
}
```